# implementing Paper-machines without zotero through python?

Tags: javascript, python, external, spidermonkey, splinter

How to externally link a code to paper machines(which is an add-on for zotero), to produce and store word clouds etc, without running actual zotero standalone/firefox add-on. I am completely new to Java and Python, so need guidance. I have done some research suggesting to do it by Python-mechanize module/Selenium/splinter or using python-spidermonkey/DOMforms. Give me an approach to follow.

Zotero source code:
http://www.zotero.org/support/dev/source_code
Intro to what paper machines does :
http://papermachines.org/?page_id=30

Comment: wait, Java or JavaScript? those are two completely different languages.

Comment: zotero's add-on papermachines has javaScript, and i need to call it through a program in python.
its a random task assigned to me and i need some help.